# Голоса за закрытие

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, закрытие-вопросов

При закрыти вопроса появляется такой баг. Раньше я считал что для голоса нужно нажать на стрелочку вверх в сообщение

[image]

Но тут прикол, голос "зачисляется", но не считается голосом "за закрытие". Поэтому цифры 3 и 6 - разные, хотя должны быть одинаковыми. Т.е. если закрывать через "закрыть" голос добавляется и туда и туда. А если нажать стрелочку... то... это просто цифорка... Думаю это всё же глюк.
Вот 
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896403/%d0%93%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b1-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82 страница. Теперь голоса 5 и 7, а я считаю правильно бы было 5 на 5 на момент "закрытия".

Comment: @AK только вот ответ лучше здесь

Comment: @älёxölüt Вопрос лучше сформулирован там. А ответ на текущий дефект начинается как будто речь не о дефекте идёт, а о фиче с названием "конвертировать голос за комментарий в". Но если есть желание оформить этот вопрос (заголовок прямо говоря так себе), то почему бы и не передубликатить в обратную сторону?

Answer (score 12):

Конвертировать голос за комментарий в голос за закрытие — не самая удачная идея, поскольку однозначного соответствия между ними не существует.

Во-первых, голоса за комментарии и голоса за закрытие появляются на разных уровнях репутации.

Во-вторых, вы можете проголосовать за несколько комментариев — но причину закрытия придется выбрать одну.

В-третьих, комментария и вовсе может не оказаться: его могут удалить автор, модератор или регулярка.

Наконец, нет надежного способа визуально отличить комментарий-закрывашку от обычного. Ну согласитесь, мало будет радости когда вы, поставив плюсик комментарию вида "ну зашибись стиль кода", внезапно обнаружите, что это была такая креативная причина закрытия?